# ASP MVC2 execute controller method in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, controller

In my ASP application I'm trying to retrieve a value from the database. From javascript I try to execute a controller method.

Javascript

```
function getCapital(country) {
//alert(country);
var url = "~/Home/Capital";
$.get(url, { country: country }, function (response) {
    $("#getCapital").html(response);
    alert(response);
});
```

Controller (Home)

```
public string Capital(string country)
{
   return capitalService.getCapital("Frankrijk");
}
```

But I get no result.

EDIT

View

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/World.js" ></script>
```

This the output of Browser Console. So sometimes it logs the URL without an error.

[image: This is the ouput]

Comment: public ActionResult Capital(string country)
{
   return capitalService.getCapital("Frankrijk");
}

Comment: @DaveClough I can't return a type string in a ActionResult method.

Comment: Yes you can,  ActionResult wraps the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is seems to be with your URL, in javascript you do not need to put '~' with your URL, you can use

```
var url = "/Home/Capital";
```

The better approach for URL in MVC is to use @URL by passing controller and action name as below

```
@Url.Action("Capital", "Home")
```

So you can modify your javascript as below, put a breakpoint in your action "Captial" and see you get a call, you can also look into the browser console and see if any error occurs.

```
function getCapital(country) {
    //alert(country);
    var url = '@Url.Action("Capital", "Home")';

    console.log(url);
    $.get(url, { country: country }, function (response) {
        $("#getCapital").html(response);
        alert(response);
    });
}
```

EDIT
OR

```
function getCapital(country) {
        //alert(country);
        var url = "/Home/Capital";

        console.log(url);
        $.get(url, { country: country }, function (response) {
            $("#getCapital").html(response);
            alert(response);
        });
    }
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: In the browserconsol I now get a ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: @NiAu Its basically the jQuery is not loaded properly or its included after the your javascript code, You must include jquery before any of these script. See the source code of your code and see where is the jQuery reference. It looks like <script src="XXXXX/jquery-xxxx.min.js"></script>. If you dont understand then share your source code of the page from browser.

Comment: @NiAu What is the Extension of your view is it (.cshtml)or (.vb.html)? did you try (var url = "/Home/Capital";) as a replacement of (var url = '@Url.Action("Capital", "Home")';)? Answer is updated.

Comment: With the new route it works. The extension of my view is .aspx. Thanks for your help!